# Twilio connection parameters missing "To" parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I'm developing a Rails Twilio-based application and want to show to my user the number that the caller is calling (because in my application, a user can be associated with multiple numbers).

Here's the code:

```
Twilio.Device.incoming (conn) ->

$("#log").text("Receiving call from:" + conn.parameters.From)
$("#log").text("Calling to:" + conn.parameters.To)
ringtone.play()
$('.answer').click ->
  ringtone.pause()
  # accept the incoming connection and start two-way audio
  conn.accept()
```

However, the `conn.parameters` object does not have a `To` parameter as the documentation says.
For now, I can get the number being called only server side, with `params["Called"]`, but that is not what I need.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here. I'd like to share some of what I learned after recently getting Twilio Client up and running.

The way I imagine your call flow is that a 'user' in your application represents an agent with multiple sales lines connected to Twilio numbers configured to a [TwiML app](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-client/how-do-i-create-a-twiml-app). When a customer or the 'caller' finds one of those numbers and dials it, you want to display to the user-agent which of the Twilio numbers the customer is calling.

In the code above `conn.parameters.To` likely represents your default_client, if you specified one. But `conn.parameters.From` should actually display the number the caller is calling, which if I am understanding correctly is the desired behavior.

Hope this helps!